# How to optimize code for running large amount of data in suitelet Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I have this small code

```
    function suitelet(request, response){


        var fromIndex = 0;
        var toIndex = 500;
        var totalItems= 0;


      var itemSearch =  nlapiCreateSearch("item", 
              [
                 ["formulanumeric: {quantityavailable} - {reorderpoint}","lessthanorequalto","0"], 
               "AND", 
               ["parent","noneof","@NONE@"]
               "AND", 
               ["locationquantityavailable","greaterthan","0"]


        ], 
                [
                   new nlobjSearchColumn("itemid",null,null).setSort(false), 
                   new nlobjSearchColumn("parent",null,null), 
                   new nlobjSearchColumn("othervendor",null,null), 
                   new nlobjSearchColumn("department",null,null), 
                   new nlobjSearchColumn("location",null,null)

                 ]
         );

        var resultSet = itemSearch.runSearch();             

        var results = resultSet.getResults(fromIndex,toIndex);          

        while(results != null && results.length > 0)
        {
            totalItems += results.length;
            fromIndex = toIndex;
            toIndex += 500;
            results = resultSet.getResults(fromIndex,toIndex);  
        }   

        response.write(totalItems);


    }
```

The problem is when i am using this filter  ["locationquantityavailable","greaterthan","0"] It is working because the results are just 400 and the total is printed.

when i am removing the filter it goes infinite and loading in the browser and data is never shown because the results are 20000

How to make it work for larger data . I am using sandbox account.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, I added a function that gets all the results. Just be careful cause there might be other ways to optimize your search. Also, keep in mind Suitelets have a timeout setting (30 secs).

```
function suitelet(request, response) {
    var itemSearch = nlapiCreateSearch("item",
            [
                ["formulanumeric: {quantityavailable} - {reorderpoint}", "lessthanorequalto", "0"],
                "AND",
                ["parent", "noneof", "@NONE@"]
                "AND",
                ["locationquantityavailable", "greaterthan", "0"]

            ],
            [
                new nlobjSearchColumn("itemid", null, null).setSort(false),
                new nlobjSearchColumn("parent", null, null),
                new nlobjSearchColumn("othervendor", null, null),
                new nlobjSearchColumn("department", null, null),
                new nlobjSearchColumn("location", null, null)

            ]);

    var results = fullSearch(itemSearch);
    var totalItems = results.length;
    response.write(totalItems);
}

function fullSearch(search) {
    var resultset = search.runSearch();
    var resultsets = [];
    var returnSearchResults = [];
    var searchid = 0;
    var startdate, enddate, resultslice;
    do {
        resultslice = getResultSlice(resultset, searchid);
        for (rs in resultslice) {
            returnSearchResults.push(resultslice[rs]);
            searchid++;
        }
    } while (resultslice.length == 1000);

    return returnSearchResults;

    //*********** HELPER FUNCTION ***********/
    function getResultSlice(resultset, searchid) {
        var resultslice = resultset.getResults(searchid, searchid + 1000);
        return resultslice;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably really don't want your user to have to wade through 20k rows.If your use case is just to create a search and show the search results (e.g. so the user can export them or further play with the results but not check some boxes to re-submit for further processing) then you could use `nlobjSearch.setRedirectURLToSearchResults();`

e.g.

```
var itemSearch =  nlapiCreateSearch("item", 
          [
             ["formulanumeric: {quantityavailable} - {reorderpoint}","lessthanorequalto","0"], 
           "AND", 
           ["parent","noneof","@NONE@"]
           "AND", 
           ["locationquantityavailable","greaterthan","0"]


    ], 
            [
               new nlobjSearchColumn("itemid",null,null).setSort(false), 
               new nlobjSearchColumn("parent",null,null), 
               new nlobjSearchColumn("othervendor",null,null), 
               new nlobjSearchColumn("department",null,null), 
               new nlobjSearchColumn("location",null,null)

             ]
     );
     itemSearch.setRedirectURLToSearchResults();
```

Now Netsuite's saved search pane will handle paging etc.

Comment: Hi, what could be the other way if I want to show these results on suitelet sublist and dont want netsuite to throw timeout or script usage limit errors ? BTW, I am using API version 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

As you code is only calculating a total, there is no need to retrieve all the data. Just have the the saved search return the total.

Here's the basic idea (I didn't test the code, so there may be some mistakes but the general idea should work).

```
function suitelet(request, response) {

    var results = nlapiSearchRecord('item', null,
        [
            ["formulanumeric: {quantityavailable} - {reorderpoint}","lessthanorequalto","0"], "AND",
            ["parent","noneof","@NONE@"]
        ], 
        [
            new nlobjSearchColumn("formulanumeric",null,'GROUP').setFormula('1'), 
            new nlobjSearchColumn('itemid',null,'COUNT')
        ]
    );

    if(results) {
        var totalItems = results[0].getValue('itemid',null,'COUNT');
        response.write(totalItems);
    }

}
```

Comment: nice but i want to use nlapiCreateSearch, calculating total was just an example. I also want the rows of other data .. It is working for 400 records but when there are more items like 20000 it is not working ..

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?